# start video record on view load in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, video-capture

I've looked through the Apple documentation but have seen no mention of how to do this, nevermind if it's even possible or not. I'd like to make it so that an iPhone/iPad begins video recording automatically when a certain view is loaded, and stops and saves when the view is dismissed. Is there any way that I can do this or am I just going to have to use the normal UI for video recording?

Comment: Go and read the docs for AVFoundation and then come back with some questions about what you need to specifically know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AVCaptureSession

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureSession

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! looking up video capture tends to result in UIImagePickerController, which is (seemingly) incapable of doing what I need.